# openbravo: Error while doing ant export.database

Tags: ant, tomcat6, java-6, openbravo

When I run `ant export.database`, I get the below error.
It shows error in procedure which is created by me.

**Error:**

```
******************************************************** 
Found differences in MOM_INPUTBOM
********************************************************
V_SEQUENCECOUNT NUMBER; 
V_RAWCOUNT NUMBER[ +] := 0;    
V_CNTSEQPRD NUMBER [ +]    V_PPV1 VARCHAR2(32);
V_CNT1 NUMBER[ +] := 0;
[ +])[ ]                      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
'There is no products in I/O Products'[ +])[ ] ;           
[now][NOW+](),V_USER_ID,[now][NOW+]      
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Raw Material already inserted'[ +])[
] ;        [ +]
********************************************************
Warning: Some of the functions and triggers which are being exported have been
detected to change if they are inserted in a PostgreSQL database
again. If you are working on an Oracle-only environment, you should
not worry about this. If you are working with PostgreSQL, you should
check that the functions and triggers are inserted in a correct way
when applying the exported module. The affected objects are:  Function
[notation=MOM_OUTSOURCESO(VARCHAR); ] Function
[notation=MOM_INPUTBOM(VARCHAR); ] Database [name=Oracle server; 515
tables; 3 sequences; 67 views; 323 functions; 341 triggers] Validating
```

Module...

Answer (score 0):

This page [PL-SQL code rules to write Oracle and Postgresql code](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/PL-SQL_code_rules_to_write_Oracle_and_Postgresql_code#Elements_not_supported_by_dbsource_manager) can help you.